# How to download files directly into an archive?

Tags: python, download, request, zip, python-zipfile

I want to download multiple files and save them in a zipfile.

Here is my code so far:

```
import zipfile
import requests
import os

pics = ['url/1.jpg', 'url/2.jpg', 'url/3.jpg']
dir = '/directory' 

with zipfile.ZipFile(dir + '/test.zip', 'w') as my_zip:
    for x in range(len(pics)):
        fn = dir + '/' + pics[x].split('/')[-1]
        
        r = requests.get(pics[x], allow_redirects=True)
        open(fn, 'wb').write(r.content)
    
        my_zip.write(fn, str(x+1) + os.path.splitext(fn)[1])
        
        os.remove(fn)
```

Is there a smarter/cleaner/shorter way to do this.
Downloading the img, then putting it into the zip and then deleting it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should you a temporary file in such cases.

This should work:

```
import requests
import zipfile
import tempfile

pics = ['http://www.princeton.edu/~dancexp/Images/1-XPAlifun.jpg',
        'http://www.princeton.edu/~dancexp/Images/1-ExposeJess.jpg',
        'http://www.princeton.edu/~dancexp/Images/JessHsurevisedlores.jpg']

picdirname = "mypics"

with zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w") as my_zip:
                     
    for pic in pics:
        response = requests.get(pic)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            tmpf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
            tmpf.write(response.content)
            tmpf.seek(0)
            my_zip.writestr(pic.split('/')[-1], tmpf.read())
            tmpf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think speed is also important. Try this code

```
import requests, zipfile, os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
directory = 'pics/'
def Save(url):
    filename = directory+url.split('/')[-1]
    try:
        try:
            res = requests.get(url)
            open(filename, 'wb').write(res.content)
        except:
            return {'filename': filename, 'status': 'cant crate file.'}
    except:
        return {'filename': filename, 'status': 'error'}
    else:
        return {'filename': filename, 'status': 'ok'}


urls = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBVja.jpg',
'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-TlrV5ArUF6s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAC0/d605oPHpYgc/photo.jpg',
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipDCR.png',
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpq5l.jpg']

pool_ = Pool(16) #It depends on your processor and the Internet to increase or decrease it
result = pool_.map(Save, urls)


with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w') as zip_file:
    for x in result:
        if x['status'] == 'ok':
            zip_file.write(x['filename'])
            os.remove(x['filename'])
            print(x['filename'], " + Added to zip file")
        else:
            print(x)
```